# Readin from socket to buffer, then read line by line from buffer to implement http language

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client, server

Everything I am dealing with is written in c language.
I am sending a request to a database server(in c), the server returns the information, I am able to read it from the socket.
My question is now that I have it in a buffer, it is stored as such:

```
[info here] [info here] \n
[info here] [info here] \n
```

I need to be able to extract each line in order to add:

```
<tr><td> [info here] [info here] \n
```

put it back onto another buffer and send that back into another socket going into a website.

This is the code I am implementing but it's not exiting the loop:

```
FILE *fp = fdopen(db_sockfd, "r");
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp))
{
    sprintf(db_buffer, "<tr><td>%s", buff);
    send(newsockfd, db_buffer, strlen(db_buffer),0);
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have written so far and what specifically you are having trouble with. "Implementing the HTTP language" is a very large task.

Comment: I apologize again, I can never get the code to display properly here.

Comment: Check this [quick example](https://github.com/Mr-Io/cserverframework#quick-example) from my repository to read line by line from a socket.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`fdopen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fdopen) function and changed your socket fd (file descriptor) into `FILE*` and then use functions like [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) in order to read lines. this solution works on linux.
for you while loop I use following code and it worked OK:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int server_socket_fd;
    int sck;
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];  
    char buff[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(1373);

    server_socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (server_socket_fd == -1)
        perror("socket()");

    if (bind(server_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,
                sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
        perror("bind()");

    if (listen(server_socket_fd, 10) == -1)
        perror("listen()"); 

    sck = accept(server_socket_fd, NULL, NULL);
    fp = fdopen(sck, "r");  
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)) {
            sprintf(buffer, "<tr><td>%s", buff);
            send(sck, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    }   
}
```

this code exit from while loop when error occurred or when client close connection.

Comment: Oh I apologize, it linux. I am using this lines, but its not exiting the loop.
FILE *fp = fdopen(db_sockfd, "r");
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp)){
sprintf(db_buffer, "<tr><td>%s", buff);
send(newsockfd, db_buffer, strlen(db_buffer),0);}

Comment: As you can see in `fgets()` man page it says: "gets() and fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read." so you must use `strlen()` output in order to break a loop and remember that when you issue read on socket and no data available your read call stops until some data available or error occurred.

Comment: can you be more specific? I have tried multiple things to exit the loop.